# How can I connect the configuration of emacs-x32 of cygwin and windows emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacs24.4

I used to use windows emacs, and store my configuration in the `C:/User/admin//Emacs/.emacs.d/init.el`.

Because I would like to use gnus which is not lucky to access in windows emacs, I plan to change to cygwin emacs to use linux commands to use gnus.

So I downloaded emacs-w32 in cygwin. Add script:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/cygdrive/C:/User/admin//Emacs/.emacs.d/")
(require 'init)
```

But why does init.el file not existed, which is surely under the folder of .emacs.d.
I think there must be some other necessities to be configured, but I have no idea.
So anyone can give me a answer how I can connect emacs configuration properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the string added to `load-path` should be something like `/cygdrive/c/User/admin/Emacs/.emacs.d`. So (1) the reference to the C drive is incorrect, and (2) folders may not contain a `/`, so make sure the folder is named and referenced correctly.